# Linkedin LogIn with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, linkedin-api

I am creating a short program in Python - Selenium to login to my Linkedin Profile, it opens the new windows but I get an error on line 13 during the debug:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
  File "C:\Users\viale\Desktop\Automation\linkedin_selenium_auto.py", line 13, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session_key']")
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/viale/Desktop/Automation/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://linkedin.com")

time.sleep(4)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session_key']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session_password']")

username.send_keys("username@gmail.com")
password.send_keys("******")

time.sleep(4)

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: What is the Selenium version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='session_key']")
```

Comment: Hi AbiSaran, it works, thank you. Last version is:

Comment: username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='session_key']")
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='session_password']")
.
.
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
.